# Display OR between two fileds in a content type

Tags: 7

I have two fields in a content type. one is file upload field. another one is link field.
Customer can either upload file or give the url to the field.

so I want to display "(OR)" between these two fields in content type.

How this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to display "(OR)" between  two fields in content type, you can achieve this in form alter

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form['#id'] == 'page-node-form'){ //contenttype-node-form

   $form['field_test']['#prefix'] = '<div class="classname"> OR';
       $form['field_test']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
       //where field_test is your file upload field
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to present your customer two options with radio check box - Upload file or Web Link. Upon selection of one of those fields, you would display the respective field - field upload or link.

If you love custom coding, you can do it with custom module with #ajax attribute on the radio field to alter and rebuild the form.

Check [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39985/how-to-ignore-the-validation-of-hidden-form-fields-in-the-user-registration-form/40153#40153) for your reference.